# If Else text does not appear to be part of the formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having trouble with if-else syntax. The error says the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula. How can I resolve this?

```
NumberVar k:={@Counting_Data}/{@Counting_Fail}
if k > 2 then
  StringVar l:="Failed"
else if k <= 2 and k>0
  StringVar l:="Promoted"
else if k = 0 then
 StringVar l:="Passed"
else  ""
```

Comment: Cleaned up language and made code easier to read ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NumberVar k:={@Counting_Data}/{@Counting_Fail};  
if k > 2 then
  StringVar l:="Failed"
else if k <= 2 and k>0 then
  l:="Promoted"
else if k = 0 then
  l:="Passed"
else ""
```

Comment: it worked thanks.But can explain why this error occurred?

Comment: the ; at the end of the first line seperates the code. You also missed a Then statement before l:="Promoted"

Comment: @4444 Just curious ... why are you editing an answer that was accepted by the OP 4 months ago?

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy Wasn't me. Ask Ajay.